# DVD Drive stuck on Acer Travelmate

Tags: laptop, laptop-repair

I'm trying to remove the DVD drive from my Acer TravelMate 6592G, but it has two lock 'switches', one of which seems stuck.  I'm very nervous about pushing it any harder, as I know too well how easily plastic casings etc. break.  Is there anything I can do to help free it?

Bonus points:  I would actually like to open up the whole machine, but it seems this is stopping the back/bottom cover from coming lose.  After removing all screws, including those inside battery and memory bays, is there anything else I should do?

Comment: Two words: "Percussive Maintenance"

Comment: It's already had liquid maintenance and is percussing no more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since you didn't mention a model number, try this web site, plenty of guides how to disassemble various Acer Travelmates.

[**How to Upgrade, Repair, Disassemble an ACER Laptop or Notebook**](http://repair4laptop.org/disassembly_acer.html)

Comment: Thanks, they only list a keyboard replacement for 6592G, but I'm sure I'll glean some info from other models.

Comment: there is that possibility :)